# Why angle of refraction parallel to base of triangle in triangular prism?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, geometric-optics

My textbook says that:

> At minimum deviation of a triangular prism, **the refracted ray is parallel to the base of the triangle**

But I feel like it's only possible if the triangle is isosceles or equilateral.

Can you please explain how it's true for some other triangle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should the ray become parallel to base in a triangular prism at minimum deviation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241295/)

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Analytic solution for angle of minimum deviation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82418/analytic-solution-for-angle-of-minimum-deviation/410797#410797). **(2)** [why does the graph of deviation angle in a prism doesn't get a symmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409713/why-does-the-graph-of-deviation-angle-in-a-prism-doesnt-get-a-symmetry/409844#409844). **(3)** [Variation of angle of minimum deviation with prism angle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351842/variation-of-angle-of-minimum-deviation-with-prism-angle?rq=1).